# How can I connect arduino to internet using wifi module

Tags: node.js, arduino, rfid, wifi

I am new to arduino..I have connected rfid reader(rfc522) and it functioning properly.Now I need to store the data received from the rfid to a online database. For that I need to connect arduino to internet and I am trying to do that with wifi module. But not able to find any good resource .Can you help me out here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to transfer your RFID data to your online database, I suggest using an ESP8266 Module. This is a low budget wifi module which can be simple connected to an Arduinoboard.

> [ESP8266 - Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678)

You can also choose for the Arduino Wemos D1 R2, which is an Arduinoboard that is compatible with the Arduino Uno but contains a Wifimodule.

> [Arduino Wemos D1 R2](http://www.wemos.cc/wiki/doku.php?id=en:d1_r2)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer is a little unclear since it's not really possible to _connect_ data to the internet. If you meant _transfer_ the data over the internet, you might want to edit your answer to clarify.